# How to get value from XML Tag using Python?

Tags: python, xml

I want to get all the 'home id' and 'away id' from the below xml script in python. Please let me know to provide further info if needed.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" charset="UTF-8" href="/xslt/hockey/schedule-v6.0.xsl"?>
<!-- Generation started @ 2023-12-11 19:32:15 UTC -->
<league xmlns="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/hockey/schedule-v6.0.xsd" id="fd560107-a85b-4388-ab0d-655ad022aff7" name="NHL" alias="NHL">
  <daily-schedule date="2023-12-11">
    <games>
      <game id="23fa5cd7-d680-4dcd-83b5-cf010257ef1f" status="scheduled" coverage="full" scheduled="2023-12-12T00:00:00Z" sr_id="sr:match:41971769" reference="20428" home_team="4416d559-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" away_team="44153da1-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44">
        <venue id="bd7b42fa-19bb-4b91-8615-214ccc3ff987" name="KeyBank Center" capacity="19070" address="1 Seymour H Knox III Plaza" city="Buffalo" state="NY" zip="14203" country="USA" time_zone="US/Eastern" sr_id="sr:venue:5950"/>
        <home id="4416d559-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Buffalo Sabres" alias="BUF" sr_id="sr:team:3678" reference="7">
        </home>
        <away id="44153da1-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Arizona Coyotes" alias="ARI" sr_id="sr:team:3698" reference="53">
        </away>
        <broadcasts>
          <broadcast network="MSG-B" type="TV" channel="635-1"/>
          <broadcast network="SCRIPPS" type="TV" locale="Away"/>
          <broadcast network="ESPN+" type="Internet" locale="National"/>
        </broadcasts>
      </game>
      <game id="7026bc87-b286-40ac-92af-1ce88b17dec2" status="scheduled" coverage="full" scheduled="2023-12-12T00:00:00Z" sr_id="sr:match:41971771" reference="20429" home_team="441766b9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" away_team="441730a9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44">
        <venue id="e256f8f5-5469-43b0-a95e-8d3adb3cb7ee" name="UBS Arena" capacity="17113" address="2150 Hempstead Turnpike" city="Belmont Park" state="NY" zip="11003" country="USA" time_zone="US/Eastern" sr_id="sr:venue:59880"/>
        <home id="441766b9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="New York Islanders" alias="NYI" sr_id="sr:team:3703" reference="2">
        </home>
        <away id="441730a9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Toronto Maple Leafs" alias="TOR" sr_id="sr:team:3693" reference="10">
        </away>
        <broadcasts>
          <broadcast network="MSGSN" type="TV" channel="635"/>
          <broadcast network="ESPN+" type="Internet" locale="National"/>
        </broadcasts>
      </game>
      <game id="47979944-74f1-43af-bebd-e82fab1432ee" status="scheduled" coverage="full" scheduled="2023-12-12T01:00:00Z" sr_id="sr:match:41971773" reference="20430" home_team="44157522-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" away_team="44169bb9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44">
        <venue id="adbd1acb-a053-4944-ba15-383eda91c12e" name="American Airlines Center" capacity="18532" address="2500 Victory Avenue" city="Dallas" state="TX" zip="75219" country="USA" time_zone="US/Central" sr_id="sr:venue:5988"/>
        <home id="44157522-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Dallas Stars" alias="DAL" sr_id="sr:team:3684" reference="25">
        </home>
        <away id="44169bb9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Detroit Red Wings" alias="DET" sr_id="sr:team:3685" reference="17">
        </away>
        <broadcasts>
          <broadcast network="BSDET" type="TV" channel="663"/>
          <broadcast network="BSSWX" type="TV" channel="676-1"/>
          <broadcast network="ESPN+" type="Internet" locale="National"/>
        </broadcasts>
      </game>
      <game id="5e2b7cee-05da-429f-92cc-06678c4257bf" status="scheduled" coverage="full" scheduled="2023-12-12T02:30:00Z" sr_id="sr:match:41971775" reference="20431" home_team="4415ce44-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" away_team="44159241-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44">
        <venue id="a75eea49-c384-4edb-99f1-d5252773ec83" name="Ball Arena" capacity="18007" address="1000 Chopper Circle" city="Denver" state="CO" zip="80204" country="USA" time_zone="US/Mountain" sr_id="sr:venue:5976"/>
        <home id="4415ce44-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Colorado Avalanche" alias="COL" sr_id="sr:team:3682" reference="21">
        </home>
        <away id="44159241-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Calgary Flames" alias="CGY" sr_id="sr:team:3679" reference="20">
        </away>
        <broadcasts>
          <broadcast network="ALT" type="TV" channel="681"/>
          <broadcast network="ESPN+" type="Internet" locale="National"/>
        </broadcasts>
      </game>
    </games>
  </daily-schedule>
</league>
<!-- Generation ended @ 2023-12-11 19:32:15 UTC -->
```

I tried using beautifulsoup and xml.etree.ElementTree, yet I am struggling with how to use these tools.

```
import http.client
from datetime import datetime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

URL = "http://api.sportradar.us/nhl/trial/v7/en/games/"  + today + "/schedule.xml?api_key=tx3ccn5bhk7nb5acb4cwd8np"

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.sportradar.us")

conn.request("GET", "/nhl/trial/v7/en/games/" + today + "/schedule.xml?api_key=tx3ccn5bhk7nb5acb4cwd8np")

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

#print(data.decode("utf-8"))

###########################################################

#print(data)

#############################################################

with open('pengins_daily_schedule.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data.decode("utf-8"))

##############################################################

with open('pengins_daily_schedule.xml', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read() 

# 'xml' is the parser used. For html files, which BeautifulSoup is typically used for, it would be 'html.parser'.
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml')

################################################################

print(soup)

print('---------------------------------------------------')

##############################################################

tree = ET.parse('pengins_daily_schedule.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Comment: Please post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: @mikeyb313, I think you should not share real api key to any side for your security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example how you can get all `away`/`home` ID using `bs4`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_text = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" charset="UTF-8" href="/xslt/hockey/schedule-v6.0.xsl"?>
<!-- Generation started @ 2023-12-11 19:32:15 UTC -->
<league xmlns="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/hockey/schedule-v6.0.xsd" id="fd560107-a85b-4388-ab0d-655ad022aff7" name="NHL" alias="NHL">
  <daily-schedule date="2023-12-11">
    <games>
      <game id="23fa5cd7-d680-4dcd-83b5-cf010257ef1f" status="scheduled" coverage="full" scheduled="2023-12-12T00:00:00Z" sr_id="sr:match:41971769" reference="20428" home_team="4416d559-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" away_team="44153da1-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44">
        <venue id="bd7b42fa-19bb-4b91-8615-214ccc3ff987" name="KeyBank Center" capacity="19070" address="1 Seymour H Knox III Plaza" city="Buffalo" state="NY" zip="14203" country="USA" time_zone="US/Eastern" sr_id="sr:venue:5950"/>
        <home id="4416d559-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Buffalo Sabres" alias="BUF" sr_id="sr:team:3678" reference="7">
        </home>
        <away id="44153da1-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Arizona Coyotes" alias="ARI" sr_id="sr:team:3698" reference="53">
        </away>
        <broadcasts>
          <broadcast network="MSG-B" type="TV" channel="635-1"/>
          <broadcast network="SCRIPPS" type="TV" locale="Away"/>
          <broadcast network="ESPN+" type="Internet" locale="National"/>
        </broadcasts>
      </game>
      <game id="7026bc87-b286-40ac-92af-1ce88b17dec2" status="scheduled" coverage="full" scheduled="2023-12-12T00:00:00Z" sr_id="sr:match:41971771" reference="20429" home_team="441766b9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" away_team="441730a9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44">
        <venue id="e256f8f5-5469-43b0-a95e-8d3adb3cb7ee" name="UBS Arena" capacity="17113" address="2150 Hempstead Turnpike" city="Belmont Park" state="NY" zip="11003" country="USA" time_zone="US/Eastern" sr_id="sr:venue:59880"/>
        <home id="441766b9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="New York Islanders" alias="NYI" sr_id="sr:team:3703" reference="2">
        </home>
        <away id="441730a9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Toronto Maple Leafs" alias="TOR" sr_id="sr:team:3693" reference="10">
        </away>
        <broadcasts>
          <broadcast network="MSGSN" type="TV" channel="635"/>
          <broadcast network="ESPN+" type="Internet" locale="National"/>
        </broadcasts>
      </game>
      <game id="47979944-74f1-43af-bebd-e82fab1432ee" status="scheduled" coverage="full" scheduled="2023-12-12T01:00:00Z" sr_id="sr:match:41971773" reference="20430" home_team="44157522-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" away_team="44169bb9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44">
        <venue id="adbd1acb-a053-4944-ba15-383eda91c12e" name="American Airlines Center" capacity="18532" address="2500 Victory Avenue" city="Dallas" state="TX" zip="75219" country="USA" time_zone="US/Central" sr_id="sr:venue:5988"/>
        <home id="44157522-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Dallas Stars" alias="DAL" sr_id="sr:team:3684" reference="25">
        </home>
        <away id="44169bb9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Detroit Red Wings" alias="DET" sr_id="sr:team:3685" reference="17">
        </away>
        <broadcasts>
          <broadcast network="BSDET" type="TV" channel="663"/>
          <broadcast network="BSSWX" type="TV" channel="676-1"/>
          <broadcast network="ESPN+" type="Internet" locale="National"/>
        </broadcasts>
      </game>
      <game id="5e2b7cee-05da-429f-92cc-06678c4257bf" status="scheduled" coverage="full" scheduled="2023-12-12T02:30:00Z" sr_id="sr:match:41971775" reference="20431" home_team="4415ce44-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" away_team="44159241-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44">
        <venue id="a75eea49-c384-4edb-99f1-d5252773ec83" name="Ball Arena" capacity="18007" address="1000 Chopper Circle" city="Denver" state="CO" zip="80204" country="USA" time_zone="US/Mountain" sr_id="sr:venue:5976"/>
        <home id="4415ce44-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Colorado Avalanche" alias="COL" sr_id="sr:team:3682" reference="21">
        </home>
        <away id="44159241-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44" name="Calgary Flames" alias="CGY" sr_id="sr:team:3679" reference="20">
        </away>
        <broadcasts>
          <broadcast network="ALT" type="TV" channel="681"/>
          <broadcast network="ESPN+" type="Internet" locale="National"/>
        </broadcasts>
      </game>
    </games>
  </daily-schedule>
</league>
<!-- Generation ended @ 2023-12-11 19:32:15 UTC -->"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_text, "xml")

for game in soup.select("game"):
    home_id = game.home["id"]
    away_id = game.away["id"]

    print(f"{home_id=} {away_id=}")
```

Prints:

```
home_id='4416d559-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44' away_id='44153da1-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44'
home_id='441766b9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44' away_id='441730a9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44'
home_id='44157522-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44' away_id='44169bb9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44'
home_id='4415ce44-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44' away_id='44159241-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44'
```

Comment: @AndrejKesey, I think you get not all values from the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `requests()` and **ElementTree**, only:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
URL = "http://api.sportradar.us/nhl/trial/v7/en/games/"  + today + "/schedule.xml?api_key=tx3ccn5bhk7nb5acb4cwd8np"

res = requests.get(URL, stream=True)
res.raw.decode_content = True

nsmap = {}
away_id = []
home_id = []

for event, node in ET.iterparse(res.raw, events=['start-ns','end']):
    if event == 'start-ns':
        ns, uri = node
        nsmap[ns] = uri
        print("Namespace:", nsmap, '\n')
        
        
    if event == 'end' and node.tag == f"{{{uri}}}away":
        if node.get('id') not in away_id:
            away_id.append(node.get('id'))

    if event == 'end' and node.tag == f"{{{uri}}}home":
        if node.get('id') not in home_id:
            home_id.append(node.get('id'))

print("away_id:\n", away_id)
print("home_id:\n", home_id)
```

Output:

```
Namespace: {'': 'http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/hockey/schedule-v6.0.xsd'} 

away_id:
 ['44153da1-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '44182a9d-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '441730a9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '44179d47-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '44169bb9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '4416272f-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '44159241-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '4417d3cb-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '4418464d-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '44180e55-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44']
home_id:
 ['4417b7d7-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '4416f5e2-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '441781b9-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '441643b7-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '441660ea-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '4415ea6c-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '42376e1c-6da8-461e-9443-cfcf0a9fcc4d', '4415b0a7-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44', '1fb48e65-9688-4084-8868-02173525c3e1', '44155909-0f24-11e2-8525-18a905767e44']
```